# How to achieve MacBook-level battery life when asleep?

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, battery

How to achieve a battery life similar to MacBook's when in sleep mode?

I'm using Dell XPS 9500 with Ubuntu 22.04, and whenever I put it into sleep mode, the battery drains to 0 overnight. With MacBook though, it could be left for a month and more without being charged, and it will still be alive and able to wake up in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

Power consumption in sleep mode depends on hardware, not on any OS.

Draining a battery to 0 overnight looks unreal for any hardware. So probably your system doesn't really suspend. This may be fixed in a OS.

I don't see how MacBook is involved. Why would you expect a Dell work like MacBook? Probably hibernation is used there.

My suggestion is:

1. Make sure that your system really suspends.
2. Enable hibernation instead of sleep. It can keep a battery charged for a long time.

Comment: How to enable hibernation with Secure Boot? I see there is a lot of tutorials involving regular boot, but found none with Secure Boot.